# Meaning of "One day you'll lay an egg too many and it'll crack under you."

Tags: meaning, expressions, literature

I'm reading a play and I cannot understand the meaning of this expression.

Somebody pulls a trick and laughs to himself. The other says, "One day you'll lay an egg too many and it'll crack under you."

What does he mean? Does he mean that one day the other party fails bad that he gets ashamed or something?

Comment: It's an attempt at a novel extended metaphor (6 Google hits for "lay an egg too many"), but as 'lay an egg' itself means (in the metaphorical usage) 'bomb; flop; fail miserably in public' it looks dubiously tautological.

Comment: so the overall meaning is that one day he fails but the playwright has chosen to decorate it with extended metaphor?

Comment: The intended meaning is doubtless what you take it to be. // Decorating eggs needs skill :)

Comment: thank you. that helped a lot. :)

Comment: The phrase "lay an egg" meaning, as @EdwinAshworth pointed out, "bomb; flop; fail miserably in public," I have heard used most frequently referring to punchlines or other types of humor, such as practical jokes. This appears to be the context in your quote. Therefore, I would interpret the quote to mean, "One day you'll pull one practical joke too many, and you will suffer the consequences."

Comment: great thanks :)